# How can I synchronize 2 tables in same database by using sync framework?

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have really strange problem.  I have been trying to synchronize 2 tables but they are localized in same db. It is easy if you have 2 tables and 2 database (ClientDb and ServerDb). I don't have a ClientDb. But i have 2 tables. If you have 2 tables(they should be compared) in same database,Sync is not working in the same db. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

you can sync tables using Sync Fx even if they're on the same database. nothing fancy about it, just point the sync providers connection strings to the same database. fyi, Sync Fx don't compare tables